# Is there equivalent statement in EF for the LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a method that gets participants that are not blocked and are not self from a specific chat room. Is there a way to put all the statements in one DB statement, a more elegant **compact** solution?

```
  Task<IList<ChatParticipant>> GetParticipants(int chatId, int excludeUserId)
        { 
            
            var chatParticipants = await Context.ChatParticipant
                .Include(x => x.Chat)
                .Include(x => x.Participant)
                .Where(c => c.ParticipantId != excludeUserId)
                .ToListAsync();
            
            var blockers = await Context.BlockedParticipant 
                .Include(x => x.Blocker)
                .Where(c => c.BlockedId == excludeUserId)
                .Select(x => x.Blocker)
                .ToListAsync();
             
            
            var result = chatParticipants.Where(p => blockers.All(p2 => p2.Id != p.ParticipantId)).ToList();
            
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Why?  What advantage does it have to make code that is easy to understand more complicated.   Merging statements does not improve the execution speed, just make the code harder to maintain and for other people to understand.

Comment: A agree that it's harder to read. But in my case, I have one more detail that I want to add to the method and that is pagination and for that, a need a similar method for participants count. It makes it pretty ugly, and a lot of duplicate of code. The reason that I asked a question is that I'm weak in EF and wondered if there were a better solution.

Comment: What if you remove the `await` and `ToListAsync` on the two subqueries and put them on the `result` query? What flavor of EF?

Comment: EF Core 3.1.2.   That also a thing, I would like to have await on toList in LINQ statement also but it is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree that keeping the queries separate improves readability, the other consideration is that the two queries will load **all** respective data into memory before filtering and pagination etc. This will be expensive on server resources. Having a stab at the relationship, you could try something like:

```
Task<IList<ChatParticipant>> GetParticipants(int chatId, int excludeUserId)
{ 

    var chatParticipants = await Context.ChatParticipant
        .Include(x => x.Chat)
        .Include(x => x.Participant)
        .Where(c => c.ParticipantId != excludeUserId
            && !Context.BlockedParticipant.Any(b => 
                 b.BlockedId == excludeUserId && b.Blocker.Id == c.ParticipantId))
        .ToListAsync();

    return chatPaticipants;
}
```

I believe the method should also be marked as `async` to facilitate the `await` and avoid potential multi-thread access on the DbContext.  I'm not 100% sure that I've captured the relationship between the blocker & participant, but that was what I could deduce from the original queries. Consolidating them into a single query doesn't help readability, but it will avoid loading larger sets into memory prior to something like pagination.

Comment: Thanks @stevePy, you nailed. It looks really simple, and in my opinion, it does not make it harder to read. I tested and works great.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest converting the `!All` to an empty group join. I did not test this with EF, however:

```
var chatParticipants = Context.ChatParticipant
               .Include(x => x.Chat)
               .Include(x => x.Participant)
               .Where(c => c.ParticipantId != excludeUserId);

var blockers = Context.BlockedParticipant
    .Include(x => x.Blocker)
    .Where(c => c.BlockedId == excludeUserId)
    .Select(x => x.Blocker);


var ans = from cp in chatParticipants
          join bp in blockers on cp.ParticipantId equals bp.Id into bpj
          where !bpj.Any()
          select cp;
```

Comment: The statement does work and produces the same result as All, but it is not what I was asking about. Why do you think it is better to do an empty group join. it does produce more code and is harder to read.

Comment: Actually, I find this more readable. Isolating your subqueries first, prevents a huge blob of less readable code in one query.

Comment: @Gia I generally prefer not to have isolated references to other tables in queries - depending on the version of EF, this can cause a bunch of individual queries to be sent to the server for the sub-table portion of the query. I find that EF generally handles unified query translation better, though EF Core 3.0 is totally different. Some versions of EF have special trouble handling `Any` in that way. Similar to the accepted answer, this would hopefully generate a single SQL query.